# Calculate latitude longitude points of geodesic grid triangle points (preferable using python)

Tags: python, geometry, latitude-longitude, geodesic-sphere

I would like to divide a sphere with a certain radius into a geodesic grid with the triangle edges of around a certain size. As a result I would like to have a list of latitude/longitudes of all the triangle edge points (or center points). My preferred language is python.

I guess I should just carefully read the following article? http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/globalgrids-book/song-kimmerling-sahr/

Or does anyone have or know some ready code which does this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the triangles to have the same absolute size ?

Otherwise don't you just create a grid of equal Lat,Long squares and make each into two triangles?

Even if you wanted to avoid long-skinny triangles near the poles you could just use smaller longtitude intervals at higher (lower) latitiudes

Comment: Thanks for your reply ;) 
No, the triangles don't need to have the absolute size. If possible I would like to implement a standard like the Icosahedron Snyder Equal Area projection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_grid)